# What are the methodologies to create low impacting debug mode for Real Time projects?

Tags: c, debugging, embedded

I am currently involved in a real time project using a cortex m-4 without operating system.
I am here because I would like to ask you guys what are the best methods to create **a debug mode with low impact/low jitter insertions** on a real time systems.

Thank you very much

**EDIT** I really wanted to avoid printf, but apparently it's not possible. I Guess printf is slow because the IO are always slow. So debugging using a virtual platform to debug would be the solution to be less intrusive?

Comment: You might want to look at [profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) tools, ex: [gprof](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/)

Comment: Thank you for your help it will be useful. But there is no clearly and well working established methods to implement debug mode into the system's firmware?

Comment: I think your question is a bit too broad. You can use a `#define DEBUG` that would enable extra traces (to be define by you) for example but it will impact the performances: gprof would be less "intrusive".

Comment: It really depends what you want to do. You can use debug printfs to print some debug information. Sometimes when trying to debug performance issues even a printf is taking too much time, then you can use some pins and measure the signal with an oscilloscope.

Comment: Thank you Etienne, i was thinking about using the good old oscilloscope for synchronization in my project. Using _printf_ in the main loop is stressing my systems too much but it it's useful to check some informations such ADCs' values...